# Hide Navigation Controller's UI.

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am making an App in iOS and it is using a `segue` that requires a `navigation controller`.

After the `segue` takes place I do not want the `navigation controller` to show.

In other words, I do not want there to be a back button. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this for hiding navigation controller from any particular view controller,

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES; //for hiding back button
```

Comment: put this in view did load?

Comment: do you want only your back button to hide or your whole nag bar?

Comment: Both, but mainly the back button

Comment: yes view did load call when the view controller is first loaded into memory

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the same viewcontroller

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```

or in the presenting viewcontroller

```
- (void)viewWillDisAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    }
```